# Equations in Python

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I'm trying to implement an equation from a paper in Python (black square equations) -

[image]

So far I have a simplified model but I'm unable to generate the intended output (below image); I suspect the issue is with [np.exp()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html) though I'm unsure - any suggestions of how I can do this?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f     = 1e6
T     = 1/f
Omega = 2*np.pi*f

i = np.arange(0,50e-6,100e-9)
y = np.sin(Omega*i) * (i**2) * np.exp(-i)   

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(i,y,'b-')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you played with the input values? Try decreasing the frequency and extending the range of i.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the exact same variable names as in the paper, that makes things so much clearer. For time, always use `t` or  `time`, no excuses. The variable `i` is normally used for indices or complex numbers. You are also missing the variables `m` (which you hard-coded as 2), `v_0` and `h`. I guess you need to set `h` to the correct value to solve your problem. In this sort of problems, `h` is usually a *decay time*, which you, by forgetting it in the formula, implicitly took as 1 second. Given the high frequencies of your problem, this should be much shorter. Looking at your example plot, you should probably set it to a few times `T`.

Comment: +1, `h` seems to be the problem, as illustrated in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate Jacob's comment, here's what you can get by tweaking the constants:

[image: Graph]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f     = 5
Omega = 2*np.pi*f

i = np.arange(0, 10, 0.001)
y = np.sin(Omega*i) * (i**2) * np.exp(-i)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(i,y,'b-')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Or, you could keep the time scale and introduce an *h* of about 5e-6, as Bas Swinckels suggests in his answer:

```
f     = 1e6
Omega = 2*np.pi*f

i = np.arange(0,50e-6,100e-9)
y = np.sin(Omega*i) * (i**2) * np.exp(-i/5e-6)
```

This produces a very similar output.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think one primary mistake that you are making is that you are plotting `y`against `i`- which IMHO should be actually a `y`vs. `1/i`plot.
this, combined with the comment from @BasSwinckels, when you start fiddling around with the parameters, you should get closer to the *aim* plot.

Cheers! And all the best!

Comment: OK, thanks all for taking a look - yes t for time makes sense, I was using i as in index. Also, h=1 in my first look, and I know see h as the decay factor.

Comment: @BasSwinckels I stand corrected. I had tried a few plots with `1/i` and it looked like something similar but I was definitely on the wrong track. Sorry for the obfuscation @Jake French